# Remove last character from an echo variable

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

This script works great and I modified it to increment by 5. My problem is I do not need the last comma at the end and I'm not sure how to remove this.

```
for ((i=1, j=0; i <= 12 ; i++, j=j+5))
do
 echo -n "$j,"
done
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You rarely really need a loop in bash:

```
echo {0..55..5} | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Comment: Thanks I was working on the increment portion in the same format you described, however I was messing up. As for the sed makes sense.

Answer (score 14):

On GNU and a few other systems, for this particular problem, just use [`seq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq):

```
seq -s, 0 5 55
```

That gives the sequence from 0 to 55 (inclusive), separated by a comma.

---

There are a few pure-bash options, which might be useful if your problem is a bit more complicated than the example suggests. The most standard is just to use an explicit test for whether you're on the last iteration:

```
for ((i=1, j=0; i <= 12 ; i++, j=j+5))
do
 echo -n "$j"
 [ $i -lt 12 ] && echo -n ,
done
```

Here we only print out the `$j` every time, and test whether `$i` is less than 12 (i.e., we're not on the last iteration) before printing the comma.

An alternative is to build up the whole output as a single string:

```
for ((i=1, j=0; i <= 12 ; i++, j=j+5))
do
 ACCUM="$ACCUM$j,"
done
echo "${ACCUM%,}"
```

Here we make `ACCUM` hold the same thing you were printing out already, but we don't output anything in the loop itself. You can trim off the comma at the end with `${ACCUM%,}`: that [expands to](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) the value of `ACCUM` with anything at the end matching `,` cut off.

If the `seq` option works for your use case I'd go with that, though.

Comment: Note that `for ((...))` is ksh93, bash and zsh only.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of adding commas everywhere and then removing the last one, here's a potential 'pure bash' solution using the `IFS` variable with the `[*]` form of array expansion

```
a=( {0..55..5} ); (IFS=, ; printf '%s\n' "${a[*]}")
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

See  [BashGuide/Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)  for details - including an explanation of the use of the `(...)` subshell to preserve the parent shell's `IFS` value.

If you don't want to use the array approach, then you could avoid the external `sed` command by using the shell's built-in string substitution capabilities, for example (again in bash)

```
printf -v str '%s,' {0..55..5}; printf '%s\n' "${str%,}"
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a POSIX compatible solution:

```
i=-5
until [ $((i=i+5)) -eq 55 ]
    do printf ${i},
done && echo $i

###OUTPUT###
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

Alternatively you could manipulate IFS:

```
 set -- $(echo $((i=0)); until (exit $((i-55))); do echo $((i=i+5)); done)
 IFS=,
 echo "$*"

###OUTPUT###
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

But...

```
unset IFS
printf %s\\n "$@"

###OUTPUT###
0
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
50
55
```

All of the increments are still available in `$@` and are singly available in `$1` - `${12}`.

And this one's fun and loop free:

```
i= ; eval echo $(IFS=0; printf '${i:+,}$((i=i${i:++5}))%s' $(printf %012d))

###OUTPUT###
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

With `bc` and `tr`:

```
echo '0;while(a+=5<=55){",";a}'|bc|tr -d \\n

###OUTPUT###
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

or just `bc` and shell...

```
printf %s $(echo '0;while(a+=5<=55){",";a}'|bc)

###OUTPUT###
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

With GNU `dc`:

```
dc -e '[pq]sq0[rdn[,]P5+d55=qrdx]dx'

###OUTPUT###
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

I like the last the best, but I'm a sucker for an ugly `dc` script.

Answer (score 5):

The more sophisticated solutions you've received are better but for the sake of completeness, you could always just remove the final comma with `sed`:

```
for ((i=1, j=0; i <= 12 ; i++, j=j+5))
do
 echo -n "$j,"
done | sed 's/,$//'
```

Answer (score 4):

For reference, with `zsh`:

```
$ echo ${(j(,)):-{0..55..5}}
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned to simply write a backspace at the end:

```
$ printf "%s" {0..55..5},; printf "\b"
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply add a check when you reach the end:

```
for ((i=1, j=0; i <= 12 ; i++, j=j+5))
do
 if [[ $i -ne 12 ]]
 then
   echo -n "$j,"
 else
   echo -n "$j"
 fi
done
```